# How to refocus a save visualforce page to a field

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to save a custom object from visualforce and set the focus to the last field a user was on after the page refreshes. This to avoid the page from returning to the top. My users want to save periodically and not have to scroll down to the last field they were on. So I'm trying this thru a call to Javascript functions via a Command Button as follows. However the object is saving but not anchoring the page to the field they were on prior to save. Any ideas or use of a controller instead ?

```
<apex:commandButton styleClass="myClass" action="{!save}" value="Save Test" onfocus="anchor();" oncomplete="focusComplete();" />

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')}"/>
<script>
    var fieldId;
    function anchor(){          
           fieldId = $(document.activeElement); 
        }
    function focusComplete(){
           fileldId.focus();
           console.log(fieldId);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring when Salesforce updates the DOM after your action is complete. your `anchor()` function is creating a reference to a specific DOM element and storing that in a variable. However, when Salesforce completes your request, it re-draws your page basically creating a new DOM. This means your reference is no longer valid. Instead, try storing the Id or class of the active element (be careful using Id because Salesforce may change Id values during the re-render depending on what is being updated on your page). You can then use jQuery to find that element on the page again and give it focus. This would look something like:

```
var fieldId;
function anchor(){          
   fieldId = $(document.activeElement).attr('id'); 
}
function focusComplete(){
   $('#' + fileldId).focus();
}
```

Comment: Strange, using your code above called from my button below and the page still goes to the top. What could be going on ?  <apex:commandButton styleClass="myClass" action="{!save}" value="Save Test"  reRender="section2" onfocus="anchor();" oncomplete="focusComplete();"   />

Comment: If you add a `console.log(fieldId);` to the `focusComplete();` function, does it print out an id that matches the id you see on the element after the rerender? Also be wary of jQuery's handling of colons in id values if your id is a Visualforce generated id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552462/handling-colon-in-element-id-with-jquery

Comment: No id shows on the console but I'm not able to connect to the jquery static resource:  https://c.cs21.visual.force.com/resource/1447465137000/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js 404 (Not Found)  I updated the code above.